# How to deal with Unicode strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, irb

I've seen follownig construction in a tutorial of Ruby:

```
irb(main):001:0> "abc".each_byte { |c| printf "<%c>", c }
<a><b><c>=> "abc"
```

However, if I put string `Здравствуйте!` instead of `abc`, I get

```
irb(main):003:0> "Здравствуйте!".each_byte { |c| printf "<%c>", c }
<Ð><><Ð><´><Ñ><><Ð><°><Ð><²><Ñ><><Ñ><><Ð><²><Ñ><><Ð><¹><Ñ><><Ð><µ><!>=> "Здравствуйте!"
```

How to deal with Unicode strings?

```
irb(main):005:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"
```

Comment: What did you expect when you used a method called "each *byte*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
▶ "Здравствуйте!".each_char { |c| printf "<%c>", c }
# ⇒ <З><д><р><а><в><с><т><в><у><й><т><е><!>=> "Здравствуйте!"
```

Byte is byte, while char is char, consisting of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

A byte is 8 bits. But unicode characters can take up multiple bytes when stored on your computer. So for example, lets say the integer code for some unicode character is 8,000, which is what is actually stored on your computer. When ruby reads in 8,000, ruby knows that represents some unicode character. However, 8,000 cannot be stored in one byte on your computer(the largest number that can be stored in one byte is 1111 1111, which is 255).  If you tell ruby that each byte of the several bytes stored on your computer for 8,000 represents one character, i.e. by calling each_byte(), then ruby will never see the 8,000.  Instead, ruby will read in a piece of 8,000 and think that represents one character, then read in another piece of 8,000 and think that represents another character.

each_byte() tells ruby to ignore the clusters of bytes, and just read in one byte at a time and then determine what character is represented by the integer stored in that byte.

Comment: Trivia: 8000 (decimal) is ὀ GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON WITH PSILI